Can I dynamically register a domain in Grails-gorm?
with gorm-hibernate5-spring-boot:8.1.0
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
   <artifactId>gorm-hibernate5-spring-boot</artifactId>
   <version>8.1.0</version>
</dependency>

my code was:
def groovyCode = """
      package com.example.gorm.entity

      import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity
      import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity
      
      @Entity
      class Person implements{
          String firstName
          String lastName
      }

      """
      def groovyClass2= loader.parseClass(groovyCode);
      def person = groovyClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
      person.invokeMethod("find", { lastName == "John" })

Running the above code will throw an exception:
Either class [com.example.newgorm.entity.Person] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.

I found that domain will be registered to STATIC_APIS in GormEnhancer.groovy at project startup. Can I dynamically register Person domain now?
    /**
     * Registers a new entity with the GORM enhancer
     *
     * @param entity The entity
     */
    void registerEntity(PersistentEntity entity) {
        Datastore datastore = this.datastore
        if (appliesToDatastore(datastore, entity)) {
            def cls = entity.javaClass

            List<String> qualifiers = allQualifiers(this.datastore, entity)
            if(!qualifiers.contains(ConnectionSource.DEFAULT)) {
                def firstQualifier = qualifiers.first()
                def staticApi = getStaticApi(cls, firstQualifier)
                def name = entity.name
                STATIC_APIS.get(ConnectionSource.DEFAULT).put(name, staticApi)
                def instanceApi = getInstanceApi(cls, firstQualifier)
                INSTANCE_APIS.get(ConnectionSource.DEFAULT).put(name, instanceApi)
                def validationApi = getValidationApi(cls, firstQualifier)
                VALIDATION_APIS.get(ConnectionSource.DEFAULT).put(name, validationApi)
                DATASTORES.get(ConnectionSource.DEFAULT).put(name, this.datastore)

            }
            for (qualifier in qualifiers) {
                def staticApi = getStaticApi(cls, qualifier)
                def name = entity.name
                STATIC_APIS.get(qualifier).put(name, staticApi)
                def instanceApi = getInstanceApi(cls, qualifier)
                INSTANCE_APIS.get(qualifier).put(name, instanceApi)
                def validationApi = getValidationApi(cls, qualifier)
                VALIDATION_APIS.get(qualifier).put(name, validationApi)
                DATASTORES.get(qualifier).put(name, this.datastore)
            }
        }
    }

I tried to obtain Grails context to dynamically add domain, but all failed
